# Binomial expansion for harmonic numbers

Tags: summation

It is well known that harmonic numbers in general cannot be expressed through elementary functions. I am interested in following sums:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal S}_\theta(n):=\sum\limits_{p=0}^n \binom{n}{p} (-1)^p H_{\frac{p}{\theta}}
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ is a strictly positive integer.Now, using the integral representation of harmonic numbers I have shown that :
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal S}_1(n) &=& - \frac{1}{n} \\
{\mathcal S}_2(n) &=& - \frac{2}{n} + \Psi\left(\frac{1}{2},1,n\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
Here $\Psi$ is the Lerch zeta function.
As it seems the result consists of two parts the first one having a simple closed form and the other one being non-expressable through elementary functions. Now, of course the question is what is the result for arbitrary values of $\theta$.